# How can I run mongodb on the editor?

Tags: mongodb, sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I use editor sublime text 3

I usually run mongodb server and client like this :

[image]

I click mongod. Then I click again mongo

Seems like that, it's less efficient. Can I do that with an editor? Example sublime text 3 editor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, You can access Mongo DB using below editors.

[Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) and [MongoBooster](https://mongobooster.com/)

From above two IDE, I personally like Mongo Booster. You can find help in that perticular website.